# Poco/Data/SQLite/Connector.h: No Such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, poco

Asked a similar question recently but trying to simplify it since no one have been able to help.

I'm trying to compile a c++ program and I keep getting the error that it can't find `Poco/Data/SQLite/Connector.h`.

using: `#include "Poco/Data/SQLite/Connector.h"`

I've ran about a dozen installs trying to get this to work including:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libiodbc2 libiodbc2-dev
sudo apt-get install libpoco-dev
sudo gmake -s install under the downloaded libpoco dir.
```

I even see `src/connector.cpp` installed with the last.

New to C++ and Linux (raspbian on the pi 2), but can't seem to get the code to find this library.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue.
libmysqlclient-dev needs to be installed first for these libraries to get installed with the poco install. Just doing mysql-client doesn't do it.

Comment: On Debian 9 the package is called default-libmysqlclient-dev

Answer (score 0):

Change your path "Poco/Data/SQLite/Connector.h" to "Poco/Data/SQLite/connector.h". Hope this will help.

Comment: I tried just to make sure, but according to the documentation Connector.h is capitalized. http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Data.SQLite.Connector.html

Comment: then rename src/connector.h to src/Connector.h using command
sudo mv /src/connector.h /src/Connector.h